# Keynote problem, cannot fill shapes on some slides

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, iwork-keynote

I have a strange problem with (apple) keynote. If I create a new shape, shuch as a rectangle, I cannot always fill it with a color. Some of my master slides does not allow me to fill shapes (but I can change the border color etc).

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Are the shapes set to no-fill or invisible (I don't have keynote in front of me for the exact name) rather than color-fill?

Comment: Yes, the fill was indicated as a red slash in the toolbar. But the problem is that I could not change that from the toolbar.

(I don't know if it is important but presentation was imported from powerpoint and I added some templates by pasting in a template from another keynote presentation. )

Answer (score 1):

I came across this exact problem too.  Looks like a bug in Keynote.

**Restarting** the Keynote application fixed it for me.

Comment: So I am not alone ;-)

Answer (score -1):

First select the shape (rectangle), go to Graphic Inspector.

In the drop-down menu under *Fill*, change it to *Colour Fill*, then select the little rectangle beneath and select your colour.